# Python read in many files do some tasks output to (Excel file)

Tags: python, sql, large-data

I am somewhat familiar with Python so I would like to solve the following problem with Python. But ready made solutions in other languages is also appreciated.

I have the following problem. I have to analyze 318 data log files each file is about 8,2MB in total 2,6GB of data. This data log file contains measurements 3 seconds apart, see below for a (simplified) example.

```
Time     Time Nr:    Date    System state    System state Nr:    Temp._01    Temp._02
0:05:09 309  1-1-2020   0       " 7,4 " " 7,5 "
0:05:12 312  1-1-2020   0       " 7,5 " " 7,5 "
```

Each file contains measurements for one day, however sometimes there are multiple files for one day. There may also be short gaps, where nothing is logged.

I want to perform some simple calculations. Given unlimited ressources I would simply do the calculations for each time step. However I assume I better convert results to hourly data, to keep thing manageable. Next I would like to write the hourly results to an Excel file.

One idea would be to first extract all the data from the 318 files and write it to an SQL database. Next do the calculations and finally write hourly data to an Excel file. However I have no experience with using a SQL database. What is the best way to handle this problem? What database to use?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please show us some code, or at least tell us a bit more about the calculations you intend to do. Also, this amount of data does not seem too much, the whole thing should simply fit into the memory of an average pc.

Comment: _What database to use?_ is not an apropriate question in Stack Overflow. Please read about [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I would use pandas. First install it with pip:

> pip install pandas

I assume your data has tabs (\t) as separator. If so, you can read it with pandas.read_csv

You can loop over all the log files and concatenate them with pandas.concat

```
import pandas
df = pandas.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t") for file in list_of_files],
    axis=0,
    ignore_index=True)
```

Now you have a dataframe with all the log data. You can extract the hour of each log message.

```
df["hour"] = df["Time"].str.split(":").str[0]

    Time    Time Nr:    Date    System state    System state Nr:    Temp._01    Temp._02    hour
0   0:05:09 309 1-1-2020    0   7,4 7,5 NaN 0
1   0:05:12 312 1-1-2020    0   7,5 7,5 NaN 0
```

And to get hourly statistics, you can use a groupby by "Date" and "hour".

For example: extract the different "System state" and the number of times it was triggered per hour.

```
df.groupby(["Date", "hour"])["System state"].value_counts()

Date      hour  System state
1-1-2020  0     0               2
```

Comment: Hello Ronkov, thank you for your very clear answer, pandas seems the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, you can click on the check mark left to my answer to validate it as the good one